# codeigniter Different/separate 404 page for frontend and backend

Tags: codeigniter, routes

How can set auto route 404 page of frontend and backend different ? I have searched a long time but i have not found perfect answer.
Btw, can we make the same for error 500 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do it by using conditional statement.

go to `application/config/routes.php` and remove:

```
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

---

After that add the following code.

```
$req_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];     // $req_uri = /myproject/backend
$req_uri = explode('/', $req_uri);
$req_uri = $req_uri[2];                 // $req_uri[2] = backend

if($req_uri == 'backend'){
    $route['404_override'] = 'Backend_error';       // Not found controller for backend
}else {
    $route['404_override'] = 'Frontend_error';      // Not found controller for frontend
}
```

You can use `echo` statement to analyze further. and then do more stuff accordingly.